# how does one use an osxvideosink?

Tags: macos, nsview, gstreamer

It seems that at some point, [it became necessary to explicitly create NSViews for osxvideosink](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/osxvideosink-td971358.html) GStreamer pipelines. Does this imply that there needs to be some integration between the GObject and AppKit mainloops? What is the minimal glue code necessary to have an NSview to give to the sink [when the prepare-xwindow-id message turns up](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/osxvideosink-how-to-get-the-window-id-td2253485.html)?